# provider.vault: "address": required field is not set

Tags: jenkins, terraform, hashicorp-vault

I am integrating Jenkins pipeline with private TFE as backend and using vault to authenticate.

But terraform plan is giving me below error

Terraform v0.11.11

```
Configuring remote state backend...
Initializing Terraform configuration...
2019/05/14 00:11:01 [DEBUG] Using modified User-Agent: Terraform/0.11.11 PTFE/46ef48a
[31m
[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mprovider.vault: "address": required field is not set[0m
```

main.tf >>>>

```
provider "aws" { region = "us-east-1" } 
resource "aws_instance" "my-test-instance" { 
  ami = "ami-0080e4c5bc078760e" 
  instance_type = "t2.micro" 
  tags { Name = "test-instance" } 
}
```

Jenkins >>>

```
stage('terraform plan') { 
  steps { 
    script { 
      wrap([$class: 'VaultBuildWrapper', configuration:conf, vaultSecrets: secretz]) { 
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'VAULTAWSTOKEN', variable: 'VAULT_TOKEN')]) { 
          sh "~/bin/aws sts get-caller-identity" 
          sh "${env.TERRAFORM_HOME} plan " 
        } 
      } 
    } 
    input (message: 'Ready to apply?', ok: 'Yes') 
  } 
}
```

Comment: You can [edit] your question, don't post code in comments

Comment: Where is your vault configuration?

Comment: Defined in Jenkins file.   def secretz = [
        [$class: 'VaultSecret',
    path: "aws/sts/VaultTFE-Sandbox",
    secretValues: [ [
        $class: 'VaultSecretValue', envVar: 'AWS_SESSION_TOKEN', vaultKey: 'security_token' ], [
        $class: 'VaultSecretValue', envVar: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', vaultKey: 'access_key'],[
        $class: 'VaultSecretValue', envVar: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', vaultKey: 'secret_key']]]]

  def conf = [ $class: 'VaultConfiguration',
                          vaultUrl: 'http://17.89.120.22:8200',
                          vaultCredentialId: 'VAULT_APP_ROLE'

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the vault provider in your code and fill in the `address` field[1]

[1] https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vault/index.html#address

Comment: I did add the code in main.tf provider "vault" {
  address = "http://17.89.120.22:8200"
} but now it is failing with * provider.vault: no vault token found.. I was hoping that all the authentication will be done in Jenkins.

Comment: Set the `VAULT_TOKEN` environment variable, as stated in the documentation for the Vault provider.

Comment: Appreciate for all your help guys!!  I am a newbie here and trying to integrate Jenkins, vault and TFE.. I am not sure how to pass VAULT_TOKEN in terraform from jenkins...  This is in main.tf provider "vault" {
 address = "${var.vault_addr}"
 token = "${var.vault_token}"
}... And Jenkins has this block withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'VAULTAWSTOKEN', variable: 'VAULT_TOKEN')]) {
                    sh "~/bin/aws sts get-caller-identity"
                    sh  "${env.TERRAFORM_HOME} plan $AWS_SESSION_TOKEN "}.. Am I doing it right.